# PreparedStatement for Xpath attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a query with xpath. The values in the xpath is filled dynamically.

Query:

```
SELECT app_prof.pk_szid, app_prof.xmldata
FROM tblappprofile AS app_prof
WHERE 'Self' = 
CAST((xpath('/ApplicationProfile/ComponentIDs/ComponentID[@Family="Core"]/text()', xmldata))[1] AS TEXT)
```

For preparedStatement:

```
SELECT app_prof.pk_szid, app_prof.xmldata
FROM tblappprofile AS app_prof
WHERE ? = 
CAST((xpath('/ApplicationProfile/ComponentIDs/ComponentID[@Family= ? ]/text()', xmldata))[1] AS TEXT)
```

When I use,

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "Self");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Core");
```

results in `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1`

The 'Self' is filled correctly. `?` in attribute is not recognized. How to use `PreparedStatement` for attributes in Xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question marks inside string literals are not considered as parameter placeholders.

You need to pass the whole XPath expression as a parameter:

```
WHERE ? = CAST((xpath(?, xmldata))[1] AS TEXT)
```

another option is to dynamically create a string using the `format()` function:

```
where ? = CAST((xpath(format('/ApplicationProfile/ComponentIDs/ComponentID[@Family="%s"]/text()',?), xmldata))[1]
```

That way you can pass the value for `@Familiy` as a parameter and still keep the XPath inside the SQL if you want.

Comment: Since, only values are dynamic, I used Xpath as it is. Now, I should frame xpath separately and use it again in preparedstatement

Comment: @MaliniKennady: see my edit, there is a way to specify that value as a parameter.

Comment: Yes that works. Since preparedstatement avoids SQL injection, is this way still vulnerable to SQL injections?

Comment: @MaliniKennady: no it's not